# Finding the First Occurrence of a letter or word or space from a sentence using RE

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to Find the first occurrence of a character in a sentence using re and split based on it.

If the sentence is  'a,bc,de'

I want to split based on the first occurrence of ','

so the op will be ['a','bc,de']

I don't want to split based on ',' and concat the rest to from the last element.

I want an regular expression that will only split the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in split method, there's a parameter 'maxsplit', if maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made)

```
'a,bc,de'.split(',', 1)
```

for your case, just use

```
'a,bc,de'.split(',', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [.partition](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> 'a,bc,de'.partition(',')
('a', ',', 'bc,de')
```

Or, using a maxsep argument to [.split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> 'a,bc,de'.split(',',1)
['a', 'bc,de']
```

Or, to a [regex split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> re.split(r',','a,bc,de',maxsplit=1)
['a', 'bc,de']
```

Or, since you are using Python 3, you can do:

```
>>> first,*the_rest='a,bc,de'.split(',')
>>> first
'a'
>>> the_rest
['bc', 'de']
```